# how to open a pop up window to a link in gridview

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to build a pop-up window function in java script for my grid view and I cannot get the window to open up.

```
var oldgridcolor;
function SetMouseOver(element) {
    oldgridcolor = element.style.backgroundColor;
    element.style.backgroundColor = '#ffeb95';
    element.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    element.style.textDecoration = 'underline';
}
function SetMouseOut(element) {
    element.style.backgroundColor = oldgridcolor;
    element.style.textDecoration = 'none';

}
function SetMouseDown(element) {
    var r = confirm('Are you sure?');
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    var pathArray = url.split('/');
    var host = pathArray[1];
    var newHost = '/About.aspx';

    if (r == true) {
        window.location = host + newHost;
    }
    else {
        alert('it didnt work');
    }
    return false;
}
```

code behind

```
 protected void gvrecords_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "javascript:SetMouseOver(this)";
        e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "javascript:SetMouseOut(this)";
        e.Row.Attributes["onmousedown"] = "javascript:SetMouseDown(this)";
    }
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Implement window.open instead of window.location window.open('your page','name','width=200,height=200');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try it, it may help you.

```
function SetMouseDown(element) {
    var r = confirm('Are you sure?');
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    var pathArray = url.split('/');
    var host = pathArray[1];
    var newHost = '/About.aspx';

    if (r == true) {
        //window.location = host + newHost;

        window.open(host + newHost,'name','width=200,height=200');
    }
    else {
        alert('it didnt work');
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and help. I cannot get the javascript to redirect to the desired webpage, as it opens up the window to "server error application - resource not found". Thanks

Comment: Just alert your host + newHost variable, it is showing your expected URL or NOT

Comment: apology for the late reply, i still unable to get to the expected url.  Many thanks for your time and help.

Comment: if you will find the proper URL and if my reply is useful then mark it as Answer. Thanks

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response.  How can i direct the pop-up to the "about.aspx" page? Thanks.